# Shibboleth 3 IDP or SP setup with IP address

Tags: shibboleth

I have successful setup Shibboleth IDP and SP with separate sub domains after digging on internet.

**Example.**
 
       IDP : http://idp.url.com/

   SP  : http://sp.url.com/

Now,**My Question is:**
Is it possible to setup these IDP and SP with `static IP`? (Not a single example available on Web)

**For Example:**
IDP : http://192.168.100.240/

   SP  : http://192.168.100.133/

I have tried enough but not getting How to do this. If is it possible, what kind of changes requires for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last Resolved IP based configuration,

While installing IDP use `192.168.100.240` instead `idp.url.com` entity name. (you can use any thing for organization scope/name(like `jubinpatel.com` even using IP) )
**Only Take care about all certificates.**
 here I made mistake, create new certificates if requires and config new/changed **Password** in property files.
Also if you going to change https ports, take care of same port related **metadata** file changes and tomcat/jetty server configuration.